# How can I resolve `MyAcmeBundle:User` to `My\AcmeBundle\Entity\User` in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, naming-conventions, shorthand

How can I resolve logical entity names to full class names in Symfony2? Like `MyAcmeBundle:User` to `My\AcmeBundle\Entity\User`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the ClassMetadata from the EntityManager which will resolve the namespace into a fully qualified class name.

```
<?php
echo $manager->getClassMetadata('MyAcmeBundle:User')->getName();
```