# From VendorBundle:Entity to FQCN

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Is there a way in Symfony to convert a string like

```
VendorBundle:Foo
```

into a FQCN like

```
Vendor\Bundle\Entity\Foo
```

### Extra question

How Doctrine handle this? Because I've seen you can do something like (pseudocode)

```
->leftJoin( ..., ..., 'WITH', 'alias INSTANCE OF VendorBundle:Entity');
```

My question is due to

```
$foo = new \Vendor\Bundle\Entity\Foo();
$foo instanceof 'VendorBundle:Foo'; //false
```

Comment: Doctrine supports an alias option when configuring an entity manager.  By default, Symfony sets this to the bundle name: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#alias.  I think I saw something similar in the symfony framework.  Search for where BundleName:ControllerName gets resolved.  I think there is a service or something that resolves this.

Comment: @Cerad yes, for sure should be but I don't know where to search because, of course, I can't imagine a string to match against

Comment: Take a look at: Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerNameParser.  It basically grabs a list of bundles from the kernel and then searches for the class.  It's actually a bit confusing.  Seems to imply you could have multiple bundles with the same name.

Comment: @Cerad interesting but I'm searching for "entity" and not for controllers. However it's a good starting point if I ever would like to implement something like this.

Comment: If you just want to resolve entity classes then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406697/how-can-i-resolve-myacmebundleuser-to-my-acmebundle-entity-user-in-symfony2.  I thought you were looking for something more general.

Comment: @Cerad well, this is great. Thank you :)

Answer (score -2):

You can use the php keyword `::class` [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class)

In your case, try something like `Foo::class`

This should output a string like `Vendor\Bundle\Entity\Foo`. If you see the comments at the link however, this is not guaranteed if you do not include the correct use statement in your code(`use Vendor\Bundle\Entity\Foo`) in your controller. If you correctly include that, then you can call Foo::class.

With doctrine functions, you can use the syntax you mentioned `VendorBundle:Foo` like this:

```
$manager     = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$fooRepository  = $manager->getRepository('VendorBundle:Foo');
$fooBar = $fooRepository->find($someId);
```

For your verification, you have to check

```
$someStringToCheck = Foo::class;
$foo = new \Vendor\Bundle\Entity\Foo();
$foo instanceof $someStringToCheck //true
```

Oddly, if you do

```
$foo instanceof Foo::class
```

It returns an error

But to use `VendorBundle:Foo`, then take a look at the `AbstractManagerRegistry.php` in \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\AbstractManagerRegistry, at the `function getManagerForClass($class)`. You can do something in your code like:

```
$doctrineStyleString = 'VendorBundle:Foo';

if (strpos($doctrineStyleString, ':') !== false) 
{
    list($namespaceAlias, $simpleClassName) = explode(':', $doctrineStyleString, 2);
    $stringWithPath = $this->getDoctrine()->getAliasNamespace($namespaceAlias) . '\\' . $simpleClassName;
}
```

I took the code from that function and tried it out, so stringWithPath should print you `Vendor\Bundle\Entity\Foo`

Comment: That's not a solution at all to my question. Please, read it carefully :)

Comment: Sorry, that was a workaround to get your `Vendor\Bundle\Entity\Foo` string with other functions, see edit to use specifically `VendorBundle:Foo` to obtain the same string